# Optimizing over an Integral

Tags: integration, optimization, maxima-minima

I have to solve the following optimization problem:

$max_\tau \int_\underline{\epsilon}^\bar{\epsilon} \tau(1-\tau)^\epsilon d\epsilon$

How does one solve these with the integral. I think I may be able to do it point-wise but I am not sure.

Comment: Is $\tau$ a number or a function?

Comment: @Botond its a number.

Comment: Then @lightxbulb's answer is a good way to do it.

Comment: @Botond The issue I am running into is that when I do that, I am unable to express \tau as a function of just b and a. That is I am unable to get a closed form expression. What does this mean?

Comment: @user52932 You'll have to analyze a number of cases for different intervals of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try integrating:
$$\tau\int_{a}^{b}{(1-\tau)^xdx} =\left. \frac{\tau(1-\tau)^x}{\log(1-\tau)} \right|_a^b$$
Then take the derivative with respect to $\tau$ to find the extrema.